# Flutter: ERR_UNKOWN_URL_SCHEME when opening Facebook Messenger

Tags: android, flutter, dart, webview, facebook-messenger

I am using [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) to open Facebook chat like so:

```
...
onTap: () {
  launch("https://m.me/someUser", forceWebView: true);
},
...
```

On iOS works fine, however on Android I get `ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`.
This is because Facebook is trying to do `intent://` in order to open the Messenger app (which I don't have it installed).

I did find solutions for Java/Android on this issue, however don't know how would it work in Flutter/Dart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by changing `forceWebView` to `false`

Comment: launch is now deprecated. The new api is launchUrl. I still see this problem with launch Url. How do you overcome it?

Answer (score 0):

```dart
onTap: () {
  launch("https://m.me/someUser.com", forceWebView: true);
},

//add .com at the end of the link
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `launchUrl` then the only solution is

```dart
launchUrl(uri, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
```